# In what order does Dapper populate class members when running a select query?

Tags: c#, dapper

Assume I am running a standard select query using Dapper to populate an object using a stored procedure.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> people;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        people = con.Query<Person>("[dbo].[sp_Select_People]", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
    return people;
}
```

Person class is defined as:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Error{ get; set; }
```

And let's say the Stored Procedure being called is
`SELECT Age, Date, Error, Name FROM ...`

Which order will the class object be populated by Dapper:

- Name, Age, Date, Error -- Based on C# Class definition
- Age, Date, Error, Name -- Based on SQL Query definition
- Random
- Some other type of optimization

From personal testing using breakpoints the answer seems to be either Random or some unknown optimization scheme that I cannot figure out. Is this configurable?

I am more interested in the theoretical question, but for context the "Why" prompting this question is determining which will be populated last in order to set the Error property based on the value of other members:

```
private string _date/_age/_name/etc; <---- whichever property is populated last 
public string Date/Age/Name
{
    get { return _date; }
    set
    {
        _date = value;
        SetError();
    }
}
private void SetError()
{
    //if (Name == something && Age == something) Error = "x" 
    //if (etc...
}
```

Comment: Look at [source code](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/b272cc664d933b4b65703d26a79272d549576dff/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs). `Query<T>` leads to `QueryImpl<T>`, leads to `GetDeserializer`, leads to `GetDapperRowDeserializer`... sigh...

Comment: It is wrong to base the logic of setting errors on the order of the elements.

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you by making the basic effort to ensure your code samples are well-formatted, and not indented way to the right. I fixed the first one for you. You should edit the question to fix the other snippets, too.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I am struggling to find an alternative as it seems impossible to call a Person method for each row while Dapper fills a List<People> in my first code block. Is the only option to iterate through the entire list again once Dapper is finished?

Comment: Yes, you should separate getting data from the database and validation. Iterate through the list after Dapper is finished is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper processes columns in left-to-right order, consistent with the rules of `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` - and stores the values immediately. So: query column order.

Things get a *little* more complicated if a custom constructor exists that maps to the query, but, a: only a little, and b: that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Would it also be correct to say the behavior is _not documented_, and thus you are free to change it in the future if you find a better way? Especially in the context of this question, where such a change would then break their code, that's worth knowing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm happy to say categorically that this is a fundamental design principle of Dapper, and will be maintained (with the caveat around custom constructors)

Comment: @MarcGravell testing again with breakpoints and, at least in regards to the column order displaying in SSMS when the SP is run, the assignment order is not left to right. It starts at the left, skips to around the middle, goes two columns over to the right, then back a few to the left.. etc. Could subqueries be affecting this? Is there any reason the display order of columns in SSMS is not the true order as seen by Dapper? I checked many times over with the same result. I just noticed I am also using the * operator on one alias, maybe that is the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this isn't the correct way to do this. However, if the order really is random & you have no alternative options, you could have a count on the mapped fields & only validate once they're all mapped

```cs
public class Person
{
    private int _setCount = 0;
    private string _name;
    private string _age;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            _setCount++;
            SetError();
        }
    }

    public string Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            _setCount++;
            SetError();
        }
    }

    private void SetError()
    {
        if (_setCount != MaxNumberOfProperties) return;

        //if (Name == something && Age == something) Error = "x" 
        //if (etc...
    }
}
```

As you can see though, it becomes quite difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean. The goal was to avoid having to call SetError() manually after populating the object or making a helper class, but that is clearly the right way to go long term.